# Question about Abel's theorem regarding a particular series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

Let $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}:f_n:(1,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}:$
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n( \dfrac{x^{2k-1}}{2k-1}-\dfrac{x^{4k-2}}{4k-2}-\dfrac{x^{4k}}{4k} ) $$
I showed that the radius of convergence $\rho=1$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(1) = 1/2\ln(2)$,
$\lim_{x \to 1} f_n(x) = \ln(2)$ and that $f(x):=\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$ exits on $(-1,1)$.

However, I do not see how Abel's theorem does not apply to this problem. Any hint or explanation is appreciated.

Comment: $\lim_{x \to 1} f_n(x) = \ln(2)$ is strange as $f_n(1)$ is well defined ($f_n$ is a polynomial map) and is a rational number.

Comment: I looked it up on wolfram and they seem to agree - 
www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit++%28artanh%28x%29-1%2F2*artanh%28x%5E2%29%2B1%2F4*log%281-x%5E4%29%29+as+x-%3E1+

Comment: I think it is because what you have is not a power series. For finite $n$ we can rearrange it to make it a power series, but the series converges conditionally at $x=1$ so we cannot assert this in the infinite case.

Answer (score 1):

$$f_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n\left( \dfrac{x^{2k-1}}{2k-1}-\dfrac{x^{4k-2}}{4k-2}-\dfrac{x^{4k}}{4k} \right)$$
$$f'_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(x^{2k-2}-x^{4k-3}-x^{4k-1} \right)=-\frac{\left(x^{2 n}-1\right) \left(x^{2 n+1}+x-1\right)}{x^2-1}$$

Using partial fraction decomposition
$$f'_n(x)=\frac{x^{2 n}}{x^2-1}-\frac{x^{4 n+1}}{x^2-1}+\frac{1}{x+1}$$
Integrating
$$f_n(x)=-\frac{x^{2 n+1} }{2 n+1}\, _2F_1\left(1,n+\frac{1}{2};n+\frac{3}{2};x^2\right)+\frac{x^{4 n+2} }{2 (2 n+1)}\, _2F_1\left(1,2 n+1;2 n+2;x^2\right)+\log(x+1)$$

For an infinite $n$, the simple result
$$f_\infty(x)=\frac{1}{4} \log \left(1-x^4\right)-\frac{1}{2} \tanh ^{-1}\left(x^2\right)+\tanh^{-1}(x)$$